# Ĉu Esperanto havas substantivojn, kiuj povas nur esti pluralaj?

Tags: nouns

En la angla, oni havas ekz. *scissors* (tondilo) aŭ *trousers* (pantalono), ne ekzistas **scissor* aŭ **trouser*. Ĉu estas similaj vortoj en Esperanto, krom propraj (geografiaj ktp.) nomoj? Mi unue konsideris ge- vortoj, sed fakte "gepatro" kaj "gefrato" estas OK. ("Gefilo" ne aspektas tro uzate, sed certe povas ekzisti.)

Mi trovis ĉi tiun paĝon: [[1]](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum), sed ĝi estas tre mallonga kaj nur diras, ke ekzemploj estas "apenaŭ troveblaj". Laŭ mi, tio signifus, ke estas iom da ili. Sed definitiva respondo estus nur realaj vortoj.

Comment: Cxu ge-vortoj en la singularo estu permesataj estas granda debato. Mi mem pensas ke estas enorda uzo, sed aliaj tiam diras ke gepatro devus esti duseksa homo, do kaj virino kaj viro samtempe.

Comment: Gefilo versxajne ne kutimas cxar ni povas uzi infano en tiu senco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few words that are always or nearly always plural in Esperanto. Not only are there nouns that are always plural, but there are adjectives that are always plural.

- izomorfaj
- Marŝalaj
- pluraj
- Pontinaj

Generally these are proper names

- Alpoj
- Andoj
- Balkanoj
- Galapagoj

There are also some scientific terms that are always plural.

- anelidoj (a class of worms)

I found several more, but for some reason the online version of PIV isn't displaying them - so your guess to the meaning is as good as mine - but apparently *moreloj* always come in sets.

- protidoj
- gefireoj
- teleoj
- Galapagoj
- tuilerioj
- malkostrakoj
- Grakkoj
- holocefaloj
- moreloj
- Cevenoj
- briozoj
- antozoj

Comment: Ĉu anelido ne estus ajna ano de la anelidoj?

Comment: That's always possible, but it's listed as plural in PIV, and all references to it in the Wikipedia article (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anelidoj) are also plural. The only references to "annelid" (singular) in English that I've found are either used as an adjective, or as a reference to a platonic ideal, and not to any individual annelid worm. That's why I had the confidence to list that one separately.

Comment: From English Wikipedia: "Simon Conway Morris and John Peel reported Phragmochaeta from Sirius Passet, about 518 million years old, and concluded that it was the oldest annelid known to date. There has been vigorous debate about whether the Burgess Shale fossil Wiwaxia was a mollusc or an annelid." FYI

Comment: This is exactly what I meant when I said "platonic ideal". It's referring to the class, not to an individual example. You'll hear people say "I saw a bird, but I don't know what kind" but never" I nearly stepped on an annelid but I don't know what kind."  Regardless, I'm not sure I want to split this hair. There are 20 other words on my list. You get the general idea.

Comment: Multajn dankojn! Ŝajnas, ke vi uzis ian retejon por trovi ĉi tiujn vortojn – kiu, mi petas? Mi pensas, ke ĝi estus valora aldono al mia kolekto de retrimedoj.

Comment: Parenteze, kial "izomorfaj"? Se Esperanto ne havas ĝian propran difinon – matematike "izomorfa" estas uzata ekzakte kiel "simila" aŭ "egala": A kaj B estas izomorfaj, se B estas izomorfa al A. Ankaŭ (la reta) PIV enhavas ["izomorfa"](http://vortaro.net/#izomorfa) sen pluralo.

Comment: Laŭ PIV (1970) “izomorfaj” estas plurala. Ne, mi ne uzis retejon. Mi kontrolis paperan vortaron.

Comment: Ŝajne la plej ofta inter tiaj vortoj mankas en la supra respondo: okulvitroj.

Comment: @PaŭlPeeraerts Ĉu ĉi tio ne estus *okulvitro*? http://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/41/285x214/147311_1.jpg

Comment: Ne, tio estas "monoklo" - Vidvitro por unu okulo